# Applescript : Merging list

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to merging two list but always have an error

```
set myNewList to ""

set myClipboard to the clipboard
set theList to words of myClipboard
##set theLength to (get length of mylist)


set ColortheList to {"42f489", "5cdf64", "FFFF00", "41f4d0", "4191f4", "4286f4", "4286f4", "f44192", "f44192", "f44192", "42f989", "5cdf54", "FFFF40", "41f4d5", "4191f2", "4386f5", "4246f4", "f55192", "f46192", "f24192"}

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    copy ({item a of theList, item a of ColortheList}) to the end of the |myNewList|

end repeat
```

Return :

> error "Can’t set end of \"\" to {\"whateverfirstitemis\", \"42f489\"}." number
>   -10006 from last insertion point of ""

How can I create a new list with the items of my clipboards merge with the colorlist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **change** `set myNewList to ""` **to:**

```
set myNewList to {}
```

Otherwise `myNewList` isn't an empty `list`, it's an empty `string`.

Comment: @Kevin, That said though, you might want to consider adding some _code_ to see that what is on `the clipboard` is not an `image` and is the expected `text`.

Comment: Oh yes of course ... not sure why I wrote this at the first place , thank you !